# Inserting/overwriting a table after a paragraph (specific location) in a word file with docx python?

Tags: python, docx, python-docx, paragraph

Does anybody know how to create/update a table with the docx library in a word document at a specific location.
So e.g. after a paragraph with text 'test1'?

The idea is to check if paragraph exists in the document, overwrite the existsing table underneath if not create a new paragraph and underneath at a certain location (at certain header level).

I managed to add a paragraph after a specific paragraph but it does not seem to work with tables in the same way.

I can not seem to find a link between the paragraph objects and creating a table object underneath that paragraph object or identifying the existing table object based on the paragraph.

A bit of context on the code, the code is first reading xaml files and writing this data in a word document. The first time the code is run it will create all subheadings and text/tables. With a second run the code will be updating the text/table values as the subheadings already exist.

e.g.
template:

1. 02_BusinessProcess
2. 00_Dispatcher
3. 01_Initialization

after first run:

1. 02_BusinessProcess
   1.1 Xamlfilename
   Text
   Table
2. 00_Dispatcher
   2.1 Xamlfilenam
   Text
3. 01_Initialization

after second run:

1. 02_BusinessProcess
   1.1 Xamlfilename
   Updated Text
   Updated Table
2. 00_Dispatcher
   2.1 Xamlfilenam
   Updated Text
3. 01_Initialization

I want to add in the tables between these lines(newly created paragraphs).

```
paragraph1 = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph, xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 3'])
                        paragraph_annseq = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph1, xaml_obt.ann_seq, style=document.styles['No Spacing'])
                        paragraph_var = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_annseq, "Variables - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename,style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        paragraph_in_arg = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_var, "In_Agruments - "  + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        paragraph_io_arg = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_in_arg, "In_Out_Agruments - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_io_arg, "Out_Agruments - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
```

Or update the table in this spot if the paragraph exists in the document:

```
                if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
                    if paragraph.text == xaml_obt.xamlfilename:
                        new_para = document.paragraphs[i + 1]
                        new_para.text = xaml_obt.ann_seq + "\n\n"
                        style = document.styles['No Spacing']
                        new_para.style = style
                        new_para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
```

Here is the complete code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, filedialog
import os
import json
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
import docx
from docx.oxml.xmlchemy import OxmlElement
from docx.text.paragraph import Paragraph
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
import time
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd

class xamlinfo(object):
    def __init__(self, name: object) -> object:
        self.aut_block = str
        self.xamlfilepath = str
        self.xamlfilename = str
        self.xaml_read = None
        self.toplevelnaming = str
        self.ann_seq = str
        self.in_arguments = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Type', 'Annotation'])
        self.out_arguments = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Type', 'Annotation'])
        self.io_agruments = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Type', 'Annotation'])
        self.variables = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Annotation'])

def selectfolder():
    root = Tk()  # pointing root to Tk() to use it as Tk() in program.
    root.withdraw()
    root.attributes('-topmost', True)
    open_file = filedialog.askdirectory()
    open_file = os.path.normpath(open_file)
    print("Following filepath selected: ",open_file)
    return open_file


def assignxamlobjects(listxamls, path):
    if os.path.exists(path):
        for root,dirs,files in os.walk(path):
            for file in files:
                xaml_obt = xamlinfo(os.path.basename(file))
                xaml_obt.aut_block = os.path.basename(path)
                xaml_obt.xamlfilename = file
                xaml_obt.xamlfilepath = os.path.join(root,file)
                tree = ET.parse(xaml_obt.xamlfilepath)
                treeroot = tree.getroot()
                xaml_obt.xaml_read = treeroot
                top_sequence = treeroot.find(".//{*}Sequence")
                xaml_obt.toplevelnaming = top_sequence.attrib["DisplayName"]
                annotation = ""
                annotationelements = [x for x in top_sequence.attrib if "annotationtext" in x.lower()]
                if (len(annotationelements) > 0):
                    annotation = top_sequence.attrib[annotationelements[0]]
                xaml_obt.ann_seq = annotation
                listofelements = treeroot.findall(".//{*}Property")
                for element in listofelements:
                    if "InArgument" in element.attrib["Type"]:
                        annotation = ""
                        annotationelements = [x for x in element.attrib if "annotationtext" in x.lower()]
                        if (len(annotationelements) > 0):
                            annotation = element.attrib[annotationelements[0]]
                        xaml_obt.in_arguments = xaml_obt.in_arguments.append({0:str(element.attrib["Name"]), 1:str(element.attrib["Type"]).replace("InArgument",""),2: annotation})
                    if "InOutArgument" in element.attrib["Type"]:
                        annotation = ""
                        annotationelements = [x for x in element.attrib if "annotationtext" in x.lower()]
                        if (len(annotationelements) > 0):
                            annotation = element.attrib[annotationelements[0]]
                        xaml_obt.io_agruments = xaml_obt.io_agruments.append({0:str(element.attrib["Name"]), 1:str(element.attrib["Type"]).replace("InOutArgument",""),2: annotation})
                    if "OutArgument" in element.attrib["Type"]:
                        annotation = ""
                        annotationelements = [x for x in element.attrib if "annotationtext" in x.lower()]
                        if (len(annotationelements) > 0):
                            annotation = element.attrib[annotationelements[0]]
                        xaml_obt.out_arguments =  xaml_obt.out_arguments.append({0:str(element.attrib["Name"]), 1:str(element.attrib["Type"]).replace("OutArgument",""),2: annotation})
                listofelements = treeroot.findall(".//{*}Variable")
                for element in listofelements:
                    annotation = ""
                    annotationelements = [x for x in element.attrib if "annotationtext" in x.lower()]
                    if (len(annotationelements) > 0):
                        annotation = element.attrib[annotationelements[0]]
                    xaml_obt.variables = xaml_obt.variables.append({0:str(element.attrib["Name"]),1:annotation})
                listxamls.append(xaml_obt)
    else:
        print("The following path does not exists, please amend your project structure: "+path)
    return listxamls

def getworkflowinfo(openfile):
    jsonpath = os.path.join(openfile,"project.json")
    procestrans_path = os.path.join(openfile,"process","02_BusinessProcess")
    dispatcher_path = os.path.join(openfile,"process","00_Dispatcher")
    init_path = os.path.join(openfile,"process","01_Initialization")
    process_path = os.path.join(openfile,"Process")
    listxamls = []
    listxamls = assignxamlobjects(listxamls, path=procestrans_path)
    listxamls = assignxamlobjects(listxamls, path=dispatcher_path)
    listxamls = assignxamlobjects(listxamls, path=init_path)
    listxamls = assignxamlobjects(listxamls, path=process_path)
    with open(jsonpath) as f:
        uipathjson = json.load(f)
    return uipathjson, listxamls

def insert_paragraph_after(paragraph, text, style):
    new_p = OxmlElement('w:p')
    paragraph._p.addnext(new_p)
    new_para = Paragraph(new_p, paragraph._parent)
    if text:
        new_para.add_run(text)
    if style is not None:
        new_para.style = style
    paragraph1 = new_para
    return paragraph1

def fillxamldata(document, listofxamls):
    print("Starting to update workflow information.")
    for xaml_obt in listofxamls:
        paraexists = False
        for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
            if paragraph.text == xaml_obt.xamlfilename:
                paraexists = True
        if paraexists is True:
            for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs):
                # Check if the paragraph is a heading
                if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
                    if paragraph.text == xaml_obt.xamlfilename:
                        new_para = document.paragraphs[i + 1]
                        new_para.text = xaml_obt.ann_seq + "\n\n"
                        style = document.styles['No Spacing']
                        new_para.style = style
                        new_para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
        else:
            for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
                # Check if the paragraph is a heading
                if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'):
                    if paragraph.text == xaml_obt.aut_block:
                        paragraph1 = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph, xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 3'])
                        paragraph_annseq = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph1, xaml_obt.ann_seq, style=document.styles['No Spacing'])
                        paragraph_var = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_annseq, "Variables - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename,style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        paragraph_in_arg = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_var, "In_Agruments - "  + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        paragraph_io_arg = insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_in_arg, "In_Out_Agruments - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
                        insert_paragraph_after(paragraph_io_arg, "Out_Agruments - " + xaml_obt.xamlfilename, style=document.styles['Heading 4'])
    print("Workflow information updated successfully.\n")
    return

def filldependencies(document, jsonUI):
    print("Starting to fill dependencies.")
    dict_depend = jsonUI['dependencies']
    text = ""
    for i in dict_depend:
        text = text + i+": "+ dict_depend[i]+"\n"
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs): # Loop through all the paragraphs in the Word file
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'): # Check if the paragraph is a heading
             if 'dependencies' == paragraph.text.lower():
                new_para = document.paragraphs[i+1]
                new_para.text = text
                style = document.styles['No Spacing']
                new_para.style = style
                new_para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
    print("Dependencies updated successfully.\n")
    return

def fillgeneralinfo(document, jsonUI):
    print("Starting to fill process info.")
    text = ("Process name: "+"\t\t\t"+ jsonUI['name'] + "\n" +
    "Process description:"+"\t\t" + jsonUI['description'] +"\n" +
    "UIpath Studio version:"+"\t\t"+ jsonUI['studioVersion'] + "\n" +
    "Project version:"+"\t\t\t" + jsonUI['projectVersion'] + "\n")
    for i, paragraph in enumerate(document.paragraphs): # Loop through all the paragraphs in the Word file
        if paragraph.style.name.startswith('Heading'): # Check if the paragraph is a heading
             if 'general info' == paragraph.text.lower():
                new_para = document.paragraphs[i+1]
                new_para.text = text
                style = document.styles['No Spacing']
                new_para.style = style
                new_para.alignment = WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT
    print("Process info successfully updated.\n")
    return

def fillworddata(path, listofxamls):
    print("You seleceted the following SDD file: "+path+"\n")
    document = docx.Document(path)
    with open(path, "w") as doc:
        fillxamldata(document, listofxamls)
        filldependencies(document, jsonUI)
        fillgeneralinfo(document, jsonUI)
    document.save(path)
    return

def startmessage():
    print("###############################################################\n"+
          "                           SDD_AUT                             \n"+
          "###############################################################\n")


starttimer = time.time()
startmessage()
openfile = selectfolder()
jsonUI, listxamls = getworkflowinfo(openfile)
correct_proc = input("The information for process | " + jsonUI['name'] + " | has been read.\n"+
      "Do you want to continue? (y/n)\n")
if correct_proc.lower() == 'y':
    sdd_doc = filedialog.askopenfilename(title='Select a file')
    fillworddata(path=sdd_doc, listofxamls=listxamls)
    print("Process has been executed successfully!")
else:
    print("The process has been terminated as the incorrect project was selected.")
endtimer = time.time()
duration = endtimer - starttimer
print("Process took: " + str(duration))
```

Comment: Please share your code and show what you’ve tried so far.

Comment: You need to check each doc segment whether its a paragraph or table. If the segment is a paragraph check if the search word 'test1' exists in the text. Then cycle to the next block and check if that is a table. The only issue is how/when you decide there is no table. Should it be the absolute next block? so paragraph with search text then next block must be a table otherwise it's considered 'not exist'? Your text on what to do if a table does not exist: "if not create a new paragraph and underneath at a certain location (at certain header level)." doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @moken the idea is that i start with a template, this template already contains some paragraphs which the code can recognize and is used to add new paragraphs underneath it. exmaple first run on template: 

1. test0

2. test1

output: 

1. test0
    1.1 test0.1
         text

2. test1
   2.1 Test1.0
         Table
   2.2 Test1.1
         Text

So the code should recognize the test1 heading and create a subheading underneath with a table underneath in exmaple 2. test1 if run for the first time. 

If i run the code for a second time, it should update those values.